# How can I use twitter bootstrap in my site?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use bootstrap in my site so I can use [DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and some colleagues told me it will decrease my site response time.

Is this true and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a CSS file (118kb) & Javascript file(36kb) once minified.
If you feel this is to large you can code your own CSS/JS from scratch.

Personally I don't have an issue with boostrap.
You can load the files from a CDN to increase speed:
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Or if you don't require all the CSS/JS you can customize your own files:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Also you can put jQuery and JavaScript files at the end of your page for better user experience.